# How to change a name of more fields in Json array using Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to convert the input JSON:

for example , incoming json data structure is

```
{
  "12346565": [
    {
      "type": "13",
      "value": "3",
      "score": "5"
    },
    {
      "type": "45",
      "value": "1",
      "score": "5"
    }
  ],
  "12346777": [
    {
      "type": "41",
      "value": "10",
      "score": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected output is:

```
{
  "12346565": [
    {
      "model": "13",
      "v": "3"
    },
    {
      "model": "45",
      "v": "1"
    }
  ],
  "12346777": [
    {
      "model": "41",
      "v": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

1. change:

- type -> model;
- value -> v

2. remove:

- score

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modify and remove transformation specs consecutively such as

```json
[
  {
    // generate new pairs with values copied from the former attributes 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "model": "@(1,type)",
          "v": "@(1,value)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of undesired attributes 
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "type": "",
          "value": "",
          "score": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]